# Problemas em exibir dados no modal com foreach

Tags: php, modal

Sou novo em PHP e estou com muitas dificuldades em exibir as informações do banco de dados através de um modal, estou acessando o banco 
por um `foreach`, mas o problema é que ele só exibe o modal com o ultimo registro.

trecho do código:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#Id</th>
            <th>Nome | Paciente</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Exame</th>
            <th>Médico Solicitante</th>
            <th>Convênio</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

  <?php foreach($dwl->findAll() as $value):?>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value->co_patientid; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->na_patientname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->na_studydate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->na_description; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->na_requestername; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->na_insuranceplan; ?></td>
    <td>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalView-<?php echo $value->co_patientid; ?>">Visualizar</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

<?php endforeach ; ?>

 </table>
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalView-<?php echo $value->co_patientid; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalWorkView"><td>Informações</td></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">

          <p><b>#Id:</b> <?php echo $value->co_patientid; ?> </p>
          <p><b>Paciente:</b> <?php echo $value->na_patientname; ?> </p>
          <p><b>Data do Exame:</b> <?php echo $value->na_studydate; ?> </p>
          <p><b>Descrição Exame:</b> <?php echo $value->na_description; ?> </p>
          <p><b>Médico Solivitante:</b> <?php echo $value->na_requestername; ?> </p>
          <p><b>Convênio:</b> <?php echo $value->na_insuranceplan; ?> </p>
          <p><b><hr></b></p>
          <p><b>Comentário</p></b>
          <p><?php echo $value->na_comment; ?> </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar os valores no modal com javascript da seguinte forma.

No botão que chama o modal fica dessa forma.

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data- 
     target="#ModalView-<?php echo $value->co_patientid; ?> onclick - 
     "setModal(co_patientid)" ">Visualizar</button>
```

O java script dessa forma.

```
  function setModal(co_patientid){
     document.getElementById('co_patientid').value = co_patientid;
}
```

E no campo do modal poderia criar algo semelhante

```
   <p id="co_patientid"></p>
```

Para que funcione precisa baixa e importar o java script para sua pagina/projeto.

Usando o blade não fica muito legal mas pode passar o modal para dentro do foreach que exiber os resultados na tabela.